# php cookie not working on live when language change

Tags: php, cookies

i have a one form and dropdown of language.there are two languages (English and swedish).My problem is when i select english or swedish language the cookie is not updated where my selected dropdown language.This functionality working fine in localhost but not working on live server.
please help me.Thanks in advance.

Comment: and where is form or code?

Comment: the form is after login in user profile page

Comment: Sounds alot like a javascript is not called on live server because of a wrong path, path that was setup on localhost.

Comment: Cookies are the wrong method of storing a language preference anyway. Language should be present in the URL, otherwise other clients such a search engines won’t be able to handle it properly.

Comment: so which method you prefer for this concept when language selected to full site language change?